# "Unfortunately application has stopped" i didnt find any syntax error in my program pls hel me

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I developed my application using android studio.i didnt find any syntax error but application is not working pls help me.whenever i am pressing any button in the app its showing  "Unfortunately application has stopped"

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
int quantity=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void submitOrder(){
EditText nameField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Enter_your_name);
String name = nameField.getText().toString();
CheckBox whippedCreamCheckBox =(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.whipped_cream_checkbox);
boolean hasWhippedCream=whippedCreamCheckBox.isChecked();
CheckBox chocolateCheckBox =(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Chocolate_checkbox);
boolean hasChocolate=chocolateCheckBox.isChecked();
int price=calculatePrice(quantity,hasWhippedCream,hasChocolate);
String priceMessage=createOrderSummary(name,price,hasWhippedCream,hasChocolate);
displayMessage(priceMessage);

}
public void increment(View view){
quantity=quantity+1;
displayQuantity(quantity);
}
public void decrement(View view){
quantity+=+1;
displayQuantity(quantity);
}
private void displayMessage(String message){
TextView orderSummaryTextView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.order_summary_text_view);
orderSummaryTextView.setText(message);}
private void displayQuantity(int numberOfCoffees){
    TextView quantityTextView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
    quantityTextView.setText(numberOfCoffees);

}

private String createOrderSummary(String name,int price,boolean addWhippedCream,boolean hasChocolate) {
    String priceMessage="Name:"+name;
    priceMessage+="\nAdd whipped cream?" + addWhippedCream;
    priceMessage+="\nAdd Chocolate?" + hasChocolate;
    priceMessage+="\nquantity:"+quantity;
    priceMessage+="\nTotal:"+price;
    priceMessage+="\n Thank you!";
    return priceMessage;

}
private int calculatePrice(int quantity,boolean addWhippedCream,boolean addChocolate){
    int basePrice=5;
    if(addWhippedCream){
        basePrice=basePrice+1;
    }
    if (addChocolate){
        basePrice=basePrice+2;

    }
         return basePrice*quantity;
}
}
```

`XML file :`

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"


    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Enter_your_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="name"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"/>
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/whipped_cream_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Whipped cream"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/Chocolate_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Chocolate"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Quantity"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:onClick="decrement"
                android:text="-" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:onClick="increment"
                android:text="+" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="order summary"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textAllCaps="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/order_summary_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="$0"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:onClick="submitOrder"
            android:text="Order" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Can you add the error messages from logcat that appear when the app crashes? That will help us identify the source of the problem.

Comment: add what the LogCat says

Comment: please put your LogCat output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

submitOrder() should have a parameter (View view)